# hello everyone, I'm getting an error while establishing the connection, can anyone help me to solve this problem...thanks in advance

Tags: php, mysqli

> Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($result) must be of type mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud2021\pertemuan9\index.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crud2021\pertemuan9\index.php(13): mysqli_fetch_array(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud2021\pertemuan9\index.php on line 13[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIP67.png)

Comment: Probably the query failed

Comment: This error is unrelated to establishing the connection. It occurs while trying to read the results of the query.